# Build a new linear mapping $\psi$ and the matrix of this mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

**Task:**

The linear mapping $\phi: \mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ in a pair of standard bases has a linear mapping matrix A:

\begin{equation*}
A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
2 & -2 & -3 & 3 & 3 \newline
-2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & -1 \newline
-5 & -4 & -1 & -6 & -6 \newline
3 & 5 & 3 & -1 & 1 \newline
-20 & 10 & 21 & 5 & -11
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}

We need to build some other mapping $\psi: \mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^5$, for whom Ker$\psi =$Im$\phi$ and Im$\psi =$ Ker$\phi$ and write the linear mapping of $\psi$ matrix in a pair of standard bases.

**My thinking:**
It turns out that the new $\psi$ mapping has a set of basic vectors of its core that must match the set of basic vectors of the $\phi$ mapping image, and the set of basic vectors of the $\psi$ mapping image must match the set of basic vectors of the $\phi$ kernel. (by matching sets of sets of basis vectors, I mean the equality of vector subspaces that are generated by the linear shell of these sets of basis vectors).

I have already found that the basis of the $\phi$ mapping image (Im $\phi$) will be the following three vectors:

\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -2 & -3 \newline
-2 & 3 & 4 \newline
-5 & -4 & -1 \newline
3 & 5 & 3 \newline
-20 & 10 & 21
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}

And the basis of the kernel of the $\phi$ (Ker $\phi$) mapping will be these two vectors:
\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-43 & -23 \newline
71 & 37 \newline
-75 & -39 \newline
1 & 0 \newline
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}

It seems to me that the mapping of $\psi$ should be the inverse mapping to $\phi$. We can say that let the basic vectors of the $\psi$ kernel be those three basic vectors from the $\phi$ mapping image, and let the basic vectors of the $\psi$ image be those two vectors from the $\phi$ kernel that I showed above. but I don't quite understand how to write the linear mapping matrix for the new $\psi$ mapping.

**Please write an algorithm that will allow to build a linear mapping matrix for $\psi$ based on the data that I have provided**

Comment: One way (probably not the best) to do this is this: you know that a linear transformation is defined by where the basis vectors go. So you chose the three vectors in your image as basis vectors, and send them to zero. Then you chose any two linearly independent vectors to complete the basis, and send them to the image. This will be the desired transformation, but in a different basis. You will then need to find the change of basis matrix and transform to your original (standard) basis to get the matrix you are probably looking for.

Comment: Your idea sounds very interesting, but what exactly do you mean by "send vectors to zero". Do you mean to write the resulting vectors, which are the basis of image ϕ, into the rows of some matrix B and solve(find fundamental system of solutions) the system Bx = 0? And how to “send vectors to image”, what actions should I take with the vectors?

Comment: You need to state something about your background knowledge.  You are looking for $B$ such that $AB=\mathbf 0 =BA$.  For an oversimplified first cut, diagonalize $A=PDP^{-1}$ then $B=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ where $\lambda_i =0$ when $d_i\neq 0$ and $\lambda_i =1$ when $d_i =0$.  You can later determine why full diagonalization isn't needed.

Comment: Denote the $Ker(\phi)$ and $Im(\phi)$ ordered bases you've already found as $(v_1,v_2), (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ respectively and verify that $\beta = (v_1, v_2, u_1, u_2, u_3)$ forms a basis to the space $\mathbb{R^5}$. Does it help you to figure the next step?

Comment: I have already established that the vectors $v_{1}, v_{2}, u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}$ are linearly independent and will form a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^5$. It’s not difficult to come up with this linear mapping $\psi$, but I don’t quite understand how to construct a linear mapping matrix with such limited data. If you have ideas for a solution, please share them.